# order rows in r based on the previous row

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like the one below:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c("i1","i1","i1","i2","i2","i2","i2","i2"), 
             "from" = c("start","b","c","start","c","b","c","a"),
             "to" = c("c","a","b","c","a","c","b","b"),
             "date" = as.Date(c('2019-1-1','2019-1-2','2019-1-2','2019-1-2',
                                '2019-1-3','2019-1-3','2019-1-3','2019-1-3')),
             "rownum" = c(1:8))

View(df)

id  from to       date rownum
i1 start  c 2019-01-01      1
i1     b  a 2019-01-02      2
i1     c  b 2019-01-02      3
i2 start  c 2019-01-02      4
i2     c  a 2019-01-03      5
i2     b  c 2019-01-03      6
i2     c  b 2019-01-03      7
i2     a  b 2019-01-03      8
```

I'd like to order the rows for each id but here is my issue: I could just order this by "date" but some movements happen on the same day -- see rownum 5,6,7,8 or 2,3 -- and when that is the case, the logic has to look at the "to" value from the previous row and find the row that has the same value on the "from" column. 
So the desired output is something like this:

```
id  from to       date rownum ordern
i1 start  c 2019-01-01      1      1
i1     b  a 2019-01-02      2      3
i1     c  b 2019-01-02      3      2
i2 start  c 2019-01-02      4      1
i2     c  a 2019-01-03      5      2
i2     b  c 2019-01-03      6      4
i2     c  b 2019-01-03      7      5
i2     a  b 2019-01-03      8      3
```

So, the code below doesn't help me order the rows with the same date value.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(ordern = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

from and to values are just random string values so I can't just do something like this below:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date, from) %>%
  mutate(ordern = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

here is another example dataset:

```
df_2 <- data.frame("id" = c("i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4"), 
                 "from" = c("start","q","a","b","k","l","b","k","b","n","l","f"),
                 "to" = c("q","a","b","k","b","b","l","n","l","k","f","w"),
                 "date" = as.Date(c('2016-09-01','2016-09-01','2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2018-08-01','2018-08-07','2018-08-05','2017-06-01','2018-11-01','2017-10-01','2019-02-01','2019-02-02')),
                 "rownum" = c(1:12))
```

here is the expected outcome:

```
   id    from  to    date       rownum ordern
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <date>      <int>  <int>
 1 i4    start q     2016-09-01      1      1
 2 i4    q     a     2016-09-01      2      2
 3 i4    a     b     2017-04-01      3      3
 4 i4    b     k     2017-05-01      4      4
 5 i4    k     n     2017-06-01      8      5
 6 i4    n     k     2017-10-01     10      6
 7 i4    k     b     2018-08-01      5      7
 8 i4    b     l     2018-08-05      7      8
 9 i4    l     b     2018-08-07      6      9
10 i4    b     l     2018-11-01      9     10
11 i4    l     f     2019-02-01     11     11
12 i4    f     w     2019-02-02     12     12
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the `date` to `Date` class and use `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(date) %>% 
   mutate(new = order(match(from, to, nomatch = -1)))
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   id [2]
#  id    from  to    date       rownum   new
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <date>      <int> <int>
#1 i1    start c     2019-01-01      1     1
#2 i1    b     a     2019-01-02      2     3
#3 i1    c     b     2019-01-02      3     2
#4 i2    start c     2019-01-02      4     1
#5 i2    c     a     2019-01-03      5     2
#6 i2    b     c     2019-01-03      6     4
#7 i2    c     b     2019-01-03      7     5
#8 i2    a     b     2019-01-03      8     3
```

Comment: how is this going to help me sort the ones with the same date properly?

Comment: @Fenchurch  I get the same expected output with this method

Comment: @Fenchurch  Can you show a better example where this will create an issue.  Also, please use `dput` instead of images to test it

Comment: @Fenchurch  Reason is that I wanted to test it on different cases

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for some reason when the majority of the dates are unique. Here is an example dataframe: `df_2 <- data.frame("id" = c("i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4","i4"), 
                 "from" = c("start","q","a","b","k","l","b","k","b","n","l","f"),
                 "to" = c("q","a","b","k","b","b","l","n","l","k","f","w"),
                 "date" = as.Date(c('2016-09-01','2016-09-01','2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2018-08-01','2018-08-07','2018-08-05','2017-06-01','2018-11-01','2017-10-01','2019-02-01','2019-02-02')),
                 "rownum" = c(1:12))`

Comment: @Fenchurch What is the expected output here

Comment: it was too long for the comment section so I updated the question.